# Salesforce Javascript, Several If statements; unexpected token IF

Tags: javascript, error

Hello stackexchange community.

I'm trying to create a custom button in Salesforce that will open an email template and fill in the recipients list depending on the several Account fields. Here's the code i'm using

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}

var account = new sforce.SObject("Account");

account.id = "{!Account.Id}";

if ("{!Account.Deal_Type__c}" == "") {
    alert("Please select Deal Type");
} else {
    if ("{!Account.Deal_Type__c}" == "Renewals") {
        if ("{!Account.Supply_Type__c }" == "Option1") {
            window.open('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}}&p24= email1 &p4=email1&p5={!URLENCODE("email2;email3;email4;email5")}&retURL={!Account.Id}&template_id=00XD0000001vHyU ', 'Popup', 'height=800,width=800,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
        } else if ("{!Account.Supply_Type__c }" == "Option2") {
            window.open('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}}&p24= email1&p4=email1&p5={!URLENCODE("email6;email7;email8")}&retURL={!Account.Id}&template_id=00XD0000001vHyU ', 'Popup', 'height=800,width=800,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
        }
    } else if ("{!Account.Deal_Type__c}" == "New Business") {
        if ("{!Account.Supply_Type__c }" == "Option1") {
            window.open('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}}&p24= email1&p4=email1&p5={!URLENCODE("email2;email4;email6;email8")}&retURL={!Account.Id}&template_id=00XD0000001vHyU ', 'Popup', 'height=800,width=800,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
        } else if ("{!Account.Supply_Type__c }" == "Option2") {
            window.open('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}}&p24=email1&p4=email1&p5={!URLENCODE("email3;email5;email7")}&retURL={!Account.Id}&template_id=00XD0000001vHyU ', 'Popup', 'height=800,width=800,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason i receive an "Unexpected token If" error when i run the code. And no matter how i tried to change the positions of {}, i was not able to get a result.

Unfortunatey, my tierd brain wont be able to find a solution on it's own (im not even sure how to make those long lines in the code above visible on one page without the need of scrolling to the right, sorry:(), so I'd really apprciate if someone could take a look and point out an error, or suggest a better way of using several IF statements.

Thanks you in advance and best regards!

Comment: Very strange, because I've testet your code in my dev org and it works.

Comment: Hi mast0r! It really did work when i copied it from here -_______- probably i had redundant spaces somewhere in my original code... Anyway, many thanks for checking it!

Comment: You're not escaping the output strings. An errant quotation mark would cause the error.

Comment: I also tested and had no problems. Your code is hard to read, so I've formatted it for you.